# Forward-define a pragma for GCC

Tags: c, macros

I am looking for a solution to forward-declare/define a pragma for GCC.

I use message pragmas as todo list (#pragma message "do this and that").
However, i would like the option to enable/disable the messages completely by a construct as follows:

Warning, this is pseudo-code:

```
// Definition
#if 1 // generate todo list
#define ADD_TODO(msg) #pragma message "[todo]" msg
#else
#define ADD_TODO(msg) /*empty*/
#endif
// Usage
ADD_TODO("this may result in unitialized variables, fix this")
```

Has someone experience with such constructs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the `_Pragma` preprocessing operator (introduced in C99):

```
// Definition
#define PRAGMA(...) _Pragma(#__VA_ARGS__)

#if 1 // generate todo list
#define ADD_TODO(msg) PRAGMA( message "[todo]" msg)
#else
#define ADD_TODO(msg) /*empty*/
#endif
// Usage
ADD_TODO("this may result in unitialized variables, fix this")
```

The operator solves the problem of not being able to use preprocessor directives (such as `#pragma`) inside a `#define`). It takes a string-literal argument, which is quite impractical to construct by hand, and that is why you'll pretty much always see it wrapped in macro that constructs the string using the `#` (stringification) operator as shown in the above snippet.

Comment: Requires >= C99,  (= Section 6.10.9 of the C99 standard).

Comment: ok perfect i will check this. thank you. ( PS: i use C11 since its meanwhile 2019 :-) )